# "started to get", "started getting" or "started to getting" - which is correct?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

1. From that point things **started to get** complicated.
2. From that point things **started getting** complicated.
3. From that point things **started to getting** complicated.

Which of these sentences would be correct, if I want to imply that something happened and things are not in order anymore? All three seem correct to me. But I feel like one of them should be the most correct.

Comment: (3) is ungrammatical, (1) and (2) are both acceptable. **Start**  takes _either_ the infinitive _or_ the present participle.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 3 is clearly wrong.  We do not want to have *to* + present participle.

Answers 1 and 2 are just fine.  *Started to get* is quite a bit more common.